# jQuery: draggable bars - remember position with cookie?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cookies, drag-and-drop, draggable

hey guys,
I can't seem to get it working. I have draggable black bars that act as navigation on top of the content.

I simply want to browser to remember the position of the bars with a cookie. Whenever a user drags the bars and clicks something else (the page refreshes) the bars should stay at the last position.

I can't seem to get it working. Moreover I wish to have a simple random distribution of the bars when a user visits the site for the first time.

I've built a quick example. Maybe you know what I'm doing wrong here: http://jsfiddle.net/RZQ8H/

```
$("ul.bars li").draggable({
     stop: function(event, ui) {
         var currentPos = $(this).position();
         var currentTop = Math.round(currentPos.top);

         // save cookie when stopped dragging
         $.cookie('position' + $(this).index('li').toString(), currentTop.toString());
     }
});
```

The position when the page is loaded...

```
// initial position of elements
$("ul.bars li").each(function() {

        // if no cookie is set (first visit to page) all bars should be distributed
        // randomly across the document

        if ( $.cookie('position'+ $(this).index('li').toString()) ) {
            var doc = $(document).height() - 50;

            // random distribution of elements
            $("ul.bars li").each(function() {
                var randPos = Math.random(0)*doc;
                $(this).css('top' , randPos+'px');
            });

        } else { 

            // if a cookie exists (the bars have already been dragged)
            // remember the position

            var savedPos = $.cookie('position' + $(this).index('li').toString());            

            $(this).css({ top: savedPos + 'px' });
        }

});
```

Comment: The cookie plugin isn't loaded from the applied resource on jsfiddle

Comment: What you didn't mention is that you're [using a jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got your condition wrong way around:

```
if ($.cookie('position'+ $(this).index('li').toString()) ) {

            // random distribution of elements


        } else {

            // if a cookie exists (the bars have already been dragged)
            // remember the position

        }
```

Swap it around, so that if a cookie exists, it won't randomly distribute them.

```
   if (!$.cookie('position'+ $(this).index('li').toString()) ) {
```

Example:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/RZQ8H/3/show/

Comment: thank you, but test you example with multiple reloads. The thing is buggy. it doesn't really remember each position of the element. That's my problem. I simply want to drag a bar (then click or reload) and the bar doesn't move it's position.

Comment: @mathiregister That's because you are reloading the page before the cookie has been saved. Try moving an element, drop it, and wait for 10 seconds. It surely should be saved on reload.

Comment: thank you, but doesn't work for me. Can wait for an hour. I've removed all cookies from my browser and tried again. No chance. First off the bars are never distributed randomly withoug a bug (some don't show up) ... and when dragging (waiting) and reloading or clicking a link the positions of the bars change. Is there no way to make this simply working. Seamless withoug 10 seconds. The normal user would never wait 10 seconds, right.

Comment: It's hard for me to start troubleshooting what is wrong with your case as it is working fine from my end. Have you checked that you are even receiving the cookies?

Comment: ok, that's weird it's working for me in your example as well. However on my site it doesn't maybe it's because of wordpress or so? See it yourself. http://bit.ly/jEAwVh